# An unhandled exception occurred: Named export 'FactoryTarget' not found

Tags: angular, npm

can someone help me to understand this error when trying to build. I'm in the process of converting and angular project from ng2 to ng10 and i just randomly started getting this error.

> ng build --prod --output-hashing=none && node bundleScript/concat-build.js

An unhandled exception occurred: Named export 'FactoryTarget' not found. The requested module '@angular/compiler' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.
CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using:

import pkg from '@angular/compiler';
const { compileClassMetadata, compileDeclareClassMetadata, compileDeclareDirectiveFromMetadata, compileDirectiveFromMetadata, FactoryTarget, makeBindingParser, WrappedNodeExpr: WrappedNodeExpr5 } = pkg;

See "C:\Users\zkio8lh\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-V2OuNL\angular-errors.log" for further details.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
npm ERR! errno ENOENT

I re created the project and use the exact same files and have been trying to rebuild it but now seeing this error that im not understanding. No where in my files do i see a factorytarget refercened.